# .htaccess match exact string

Tags: string, .htaccess, parameters, match

I try to redirect on match query string the following url

`/shop.php?arttyp=Indianerflöten` to `/basiskategorie/indianerfloeten-high-spirits`

when condition is set to

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^arttyp=Indianerflöten$
```

there is no redirect. However on

```
##This works but not good
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^arttyp=.*$
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ /basiskategorie/indianerfloeten-high-spirits [NC,R=301,L]
```

How do I match exact query string with htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule works fine for me:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^arttyp=Indianerflöten$
RewriteRule  ^shop\.php$ /basiskategorie/indianerfloeten-high-spirits? [NC,R=301,L]
```

Make sure you have `?` at the end of target to strip off existing query string from target.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, I know that this rule should work but actually does not. And I do not have any idea how to debug this issue on shared hosting